# Javascript passing a function different sets of parameters

Tags: javascript

So I have a function with quite a few parameters, for example

```
function myFunction(height, width, name, surname, time){
...
}
```

The trouble is I want to use this function to send different sets of parameters.

So sometimes it would be...

```
  function myFunction(height, width, depth, name, surname, time){
    ...
    }
```

The function is used for many tasks and I don't want a long list of parameters in the function coupled with lots of spaces in the values list when the function is called.

I need something more dynamic, ideally an associative array would be passed to the function and variables created from that.

Comment: `ideally an associative array would be passed to the function` give that a try.  If you can't get it to work post your code.  If you are using jquery you can use the `extend` function to merge the passed in array with a default array.

Comment: Passing an object (what you call here an "associative array") is probably best for this particular case.

Comment: I just don't know how to type the associative array literally in the function call parenthesis e?.g myFunction(["heigh">120,... is that right

Comment: @user1209203 Mohsen's answer shows the correct syntax for this.

Comment: Here's an article which you might find interesting; http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/. Although in this case using an object as an associative array is the cleaner approach, it doesn't hurt to take a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because JavaScript doesn't have named arguments people usually use object as "Interfaces"

You can accept a single argument that is an object and have all those arguments as keys.

```
function myFunction(options){
   //access to options.height and more...

}
```

Pass arguments packed in an object to the function

```
myFunction({
  height: 100,
  widht: 300,
  ...
});
```

Comment: Ok that seems to work and can I pass a function as an object value as follows, ... width:300, print: function(){ alert("done")}});

Comment: Yes you can, but be careful with scope of that function.

Answer (score 0):

my last post was wrong. I had something different in mind. sorry for that.

you can write a function with the long lsit of paramters but you don't have to use all of them when you execute a function.

Function

```
function foo(a, b, c) {
    //body;
};
```

May be executed like this:

```
foo(a);
foo(a,b);
foo(a,b,c);
```

Inside the function check if parameters are not null and if they ar set a defaut value

```
function foo(a, b, c) {
    a = a !== 'null' ? a : defaultValue;
    b = b !== 'null' ? b : defaultValue;
    c = c !== 'null' ? c : defaultValue;
};
```

Comment: If a parameter isn't passed, its value isn't `"null"` (or `null`)...it's `undefined`.